# Check for text matching with leniency?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, fuzzy-comparison

I'm working on a application that reads a trivia question to the user and then asks the user to type an answer to see if they are correct. I want to be able to compare the user answer to the actual answer to see if there if they match to a certain degree with some leniency. For example, if an answer is "rachmaninoff" and the user enters "rakmaninoff" or "rachmaninof"... I want them to be counted as correct. Is there any method or software that does this?

Comment: Look up "Levenshtein distance" - that would be a good place to start.

Comment: Levenshtein distance and n-grams. But it still won't be perfect. Your best bet would be to provide multiple choice.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Comment: I'm personally a big fan of the Yaro-Winkler distance function. I've found that it gives better results than Levenshein distance for my use cases. An implementation in JavaScript is available here: https://github.com/zdyn/jaro-winkler-js